# Computer not detecting USB Hard Drive

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive

I have 2 identical Western Digital WDBACW0030HBK USB 3.0 hard drives.

My computer will read drive #1 when its plugged in by itself, it gets assigned drive letter X
My computer will read drive #2 when its plugged in by itself, it gets assigned letter x too

But when I plug them both in, it will only show one of them in My Computer, and not both

Whats the deal?

Comment: Do you have the WD software installed?

Comment: Are there enough free drive letters? Does it matter in which order you plug them in?

Comment: Doesnt matter what order I plug them in.  I installed the WD SES Driver for x64.  I read the drive only keeps the popups from appearing though.   I did not install the WD SmartWare Setup, which I think is just some software used to back stuff up with.

Comment: Do both USB ports share a spot on the motherboard, and does one of them require less power?

Comment: Both USB drive have their own power supply, and both USB ports are on the same USB controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into Disk Management and look for a hdd listed as "offline" right click on it and select "online" and then it will appear in My Computer...  problem solved